# Xamarin ios - How to find the iOS device uptime, that doesn't pause when asleep

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm looking for a way to get an absolute, always-incrementing system uptime on Xamarin iOS.

It should return the time since the device was last rebooted, and not be affected by changes to the system date.

All the methods I can find either pause when the device is asleep (CACurrentMediaTime, [NSProcessInfo systemUptime], mach_absolute_time) or are changed when the system date changes (sysctl/KERN_BOOTTIME).

am using the following code but it returns a constant value:

```
    public static TimeVal GetBoottime()
    {
        var pLen = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));
        sysctlbyname("kern.boottime", IntPtr.Zero, pLen, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        var length = Marshal.ReadInt32(pLen);
        var pStr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length);
        sysctlbyname("kern.boottime", pStr, pLen, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        return Marshal.PtrToStructure<TimeVal>(pStr);
    }
```

Comment: Use `clock_gettime`

Comment: How did your app know the device is rebooted?

Comment: Hello @Muthukumar, did you manage to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: HI , Did you get answer for this? Also Can you give TimeVal strcuct ?